# Jackson deserialization level

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have JSON file:

```
{
  "name1" : {
    "fields" : [
       {
         "fname": "aaa",
         "prop": "aaa",
       },
       {
         "fname": "bbb",
         "prop": "bbb",
       },
     ]
   },
  "name2" : {
    "fields" : [
       {
         "fname": "aaa",
         "prop": "aaa",
       },
       {
         "fname": "bbb",
         "prop": "bbb",
       },
     ]
   }
}
```

All i need it is to parse this json into map, where key is nameNum, and value is not parsed string with all properties:

```
{ 
name1 : String,
name2 : String
}
```

But jackson parse it too detalize:

```
{ name1: {fields: {fname : aaa,...}}}
```

How to fix it? Help please.

Answer (score 0):

This a normal behaviour of jackson. You need to implement a custom deserializer in order to make it behave the way you want.